# How can I div two columns that are summed in a select statement?

Tags: sql

This statement below gets me some data I need.

```
select TankName, COUNT(*) as Tanks, sum(Battles) as Battles, 
   SUM(victories) as Victories
from MemberTanks
where Tier = 9 and Class = 'Medium'
group by TankName
order by Tanks desc
```

I would like to show the percentage of the Victories in the resultset but I'm not sure how to do it.  I tried...

```
select TankName, COUNT(*) as Tanks, sum(Battles) as Battles, 
   SUM(victories) as Victories, SUM(Victories)/SUM(Battles) as Percentage
from MemberTanks
where Tier = 9 and Class = 'Medium'
group by TankName
order by Tanks desc
```

... but percentage came back as "0" for every row.

How can I best get this value?

Comment: Whats the datatype for Vicotires and Battles? Also,do they have any nulls.

Comment: No nulls.  They are both "int"

Comment: Ah... I think I know where this is going.  Its a casting issue, I bet.

Comment: I upvoted all the correct answers.  Cybernate's answer was first and a little more thorough so he got the checkmark.  After the comment by YetAnotherUser made the little light go off in my head I was able to solve this on my own, but I'm glad I have the opportunity to mark up some answers for everyone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you are calculating the percentage column since SUM(X) is returning a INT value, the result is getting floored and hence returning 0 as floored result

Multiply the SUM(victories) with a decimal value like 1.0 (so as to convert one operand to decimal/numeric) and then you would get correct result.

Try this:

```
SELECT TankName, 
    COUNT(*) as Tanks, 
    SUM(Battles) as Battles, 
  SUM(victories) as Victories,
    SUM(victories) * 1.0/ SUM(Battles) AS Percentage
 FROM MemberTanks
WHERE Tier = 9 
  AND Class = 'Medium'
GROUP BY TankName
ORDER BY Tanks desc
```

Also, if you are using SQL Server 2005 or above you can reduce the calculations.computations using a CTE like below:

```
WITH qry AS
(
    SELECT TankName, 
        COUNT(*) as Tanks, 
        SUM(Battles) as Battles, 
        SUM(victories) as Victories
     FROM MemberTanks
    WHERE Tier = 9 
        AND Class = 'Medium'
    GROUP BY TankName
)
SELECT a.*,
                Victories * 1.0 / Battles AS Percentage
  FROM qry a
ORDER BY Tanks DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this -

```
SUM(Convert(float, Battles))/ Sum(Convert(float, Victories))
```

See [MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175009.aspx)

> Returns the data type of the argument
>   with the higher precedence. For more
>   information, see Data Type Precedence
>   (Transact-SQL).
>
> If an integer dividend is divided by
>   an integer divisor, the result is an
>   integer that has any fractional part
>   of the result truncated.